# Changing Drupal notifications e-mail address

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am using built in Drupal 6 user module, fore user registration, forgot-your-password-emails and all that stuff.

When a notification is sent by e-mail for confirming reistration, resending passwords, etc, these are sent from a different e-mail address to the one I want.
I dont remember where I configured this setting, and cannot find where to change it again.

Can you help me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/admin/settings/site-information

Email address field.

Cheers!